# ERROR: argumento no válido para un operador unitario en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer un clusteryng analisis a partir de los resultados de coocurencia en una comunidad con el objetivo de ver si la organizacion espacial puede relacionarse con el patron de coocurrencia.

Codigo para la coocurrencia:

```
data(mas)
df <- mas
rownames(df) <- df$ID
df$ID <- NULL
library(cooccur)
cooccur.finches <- cooccur(mat=df,
                           type="spp_site",
                           thresh=TRUE,
                           spp_names=TRUE)

summary(cooccur.finches)
plot(cooccur.finches)
```

A partir de esos resultados. Donde obtengo un conjunto de especie con algún patrón de coocurrencia, ya sea random, positivo o negativo, realizo el cluster. Con el siguiente codigo:

```
#rerun cooccurrence analysis with threshold set to FALSE to be able to make effect size matrix
cooccur. finches <- cooccur(mat = df, type = "spp_site", thresh = FALSE, spp_names = TRUE)
#make effect size matrix from results of cooccur with no threshold
eff_sizes <- effect.sizes(cooccur. finches, standardized = TRUE, matrix = TRUE)
prob.table(cooccur. finches)
#convert distance matrix to normal matrix
eff_size_matrix <- as.matrix(eff_sizes)

#for loop to keep only the species that are shown in the heatmap. i.e above the threshold
species_vec <- c("especies con algún patrón de coocurrencia")
rows <- c()
for (i in 1:length(species_vec)){
  rows[i] <- grep(pattern = species_vec[i], x = rownames(eff_size_matrix))
}
eff_size_matrix <- eff_size_matrix[-rows,-rows]

#convert back to distance matrix
eff_sizes <- as.dist(eff_size_matrix)

#Clustering analysis
library(vegan)
library(fpc)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(lattice)

#run partitioned around mediod clustering on 1 - effect size matrix
cluster_output <- pam(1 - eff_sizes, k= 2, diss = TRUE)
cluster_output$data = eff_sizes

#plot the results of clustering analysis
finches _cluster <- fviz_cluster(cluster_output, repel = TRUE) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#CC79A7","#009E73")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(c("#CC79A7","#009E73"),0.4)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "cluster", override.aes = aes(label = ""))) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold")) +
  ggtitle("(c)")
```

Pero obtengo el error: ***ERROR: argumento no válido para un operador unitario en R***

En este enlace os pongo la base de datos: https://mega.nz/file/fOx0BZCT#3yNXw-QaClMuoIe9o_7xbCm0BjvEYnCdujgSX7_k488

Comment: ¿Sabes cuál es la línea que está produciendo el error? Podrías probar limpiando tu entorno para asegurarte que no haya objetos con nombres similares que oculten errores y ir evaluando línea por línea. Por el tipo de problema me suena a que es algo con signo `-` en algún subset hecho con `[]`. Ese es el error que regresa si le pasas un vector de largo 0. Quizás el bucle que "llena" a `row` está fallando y le estás pasando un vector vacío en las líneas que siguen.

Comment: Limpie el entorno de trabajo. y la linea de codigo que me da error es la siguiente: for (i in 1:length(species_vec)){
  rows[i] <- grep(pattern = species_vec[i], x = rownames(eff_size_matrix))
}
eff_size_matrix <- eff_size_matrix[-rows,-rows]

Comment: Me parecía. ¿Miraste que hay en el objeto `rows` antes de ejecutar `eff_size_matrix <- eff_size_matrix[-rows,-rows] ` ? Ahí debería haber cadenas de caracteres con los nombres nombres que están en las filas de `eff_size_matrix`. Si no tienes ninguna coincidencia entonces el vector te queda vacíos. Una solución simple sería asegurarte que los nombres de las especies que te interesan y los rownames coinciden, así no te queda el vector `rows` como `NULL`

Comment: En el rows estan los nombres de las especies que luego de ejecutar la coocurrencia tienen algun patron de asociacion. species_vec <- c("especies con algún patrón de coocurrencia") aca escribo las es con patron, eso lo entro de forma manual excatamente  que coincida con el nombre re rows 
rows <- c()   pero entonces a partir de ahi me da error. No se que pude haber hecho mal